# How to avoid the first row getting deleted while adding and removing html table rows using DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

The below fiddle is from another question. It contains the output of a dynamic addition and deletion of html table rows using javascript. The code in the fiddle gave me what i want. But i have one problem with the code. While deleting the rows one by one, the first row is also getting deleted. How can i hide the delete button only in the first row ?

http://jsfiddle.net/7AeDQ/

### HTML

```
<div id="POItablediv">
    <input type="button" id="addPOIbutton" value="Add POIs"/><br/><br/>
    <table id="POITable" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>POI</td>
            <td>Latitude</td>
            <td>Longitude</td>
            <td>Delete?</td>
            <td>Add Rows?</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td><input size=25 type="text" id="latbox"/></td>
            <td><input size=25 type="text" id="lngbox" readonly=true/></td>
            <td><input type="button" id="delPOIbutton" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>
            <td><input type="button" id="addmorePOIbutton" value="Add More POIs" onclick="insRow()"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

### JAVASCRIPT

```
function deleteRow(row)
{
    var i=row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    document.getElementById('POITable').deleteRow(i);
}


function insRow()
{
    console.log( 'hi');
    var x=document.getElementById('POITable');
    var new_row = x.rows[1].cloneNode(true);
    var len = x.rows.length;
    new_row.cells[0].innerHTML = len;

    var inp1 = new_row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    inp1.id += len;
    inp1.value = '';
    var inp2 = new_row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    inp2.id += len;
    inp2.value = '';
    x.appendChild( new_row );
}
```

Above is the code in the fiddle. Hope this helps if you can't load fiddle. It happens sometimes.

Comment: You should use jquery (the remove function is very easy to use) and also set an id number for each row. This way you can tell your js code to not delete the row with id number one.

Comment: I am voting this up just for the detail, presentation and cleanliness. Thought the questions itself isn't bad either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks elegant.

Hide the first:

```
$("table tr:eq(1) td:eq(3) input").css("display","none");
```

Then show the newly created tr:

```
var noRows = $("#POITable tr").length-1;
$("table tr:eq("+noRows+") td:eq(3) input").css("display","block");
```

Fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/Lh8KL/

Comment: it deletes all the delete buttons in the dynamically added rows too..but i want the delete button to be hidden only in the first row

Comment: thanks alot for your efforts +1..where is the link for the fiddle ?

Comment: Thanks alot saratis :) it worked with crisp...thank you so much for your help..!

Answer (score 2):

Just add this statement:

```
x.rows[1].cells[3].children[0].style.display = x.rows.length > 2 ? '' : 'none';
```

This gets a reference to the `input` element in the first row in the third cell and hides it if there is only one row.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7AeDQ/23/

Comment: Just add it to both functions, `insRow` and `deleteRow`. You also have to get a reference to the table `x` in `deleteRow`. At least this is how I understood what you want to do. If that's not it, you have to clarify your question. **Edit:** I updated it because I forgot about the header row. You could make it a bit cleaner (IMO) if you separate your table into a `thead` and `tbody` section.

Comment: I tried what u said, but it doesn't seem to work. Let me be more particular. In the fiddle above, the output shows dynamic addition and deletion of table rows. since the delete button is shows in the first row, the table can be deleted totally except the table the header. So, to restrict the user from deleting the first row, i want to hide the delete button in the first row.

Comment: thanks alot for all your efforts and time. It worked...but i have one problem that the delete button gets into the first row once i add some rows and delete all the rows. :(

Answer (score 1):

just add the following line in the script

```
    new_row.cells[3].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].removeAttribute('style');
```

Plus a little modification in the HTML (add disabled to true in the first delete button)

```
   <td><input type="button" id="delPOIbutton" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)" style="display:none"/></td>
```

Check fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7AeDQ/25/

Comment: @Ethesham thanks for your effort +1, but i dont even want the disabled image to be visible and it should be blank in that space :(